# VueJS - Show an empty v-html tag with a variable

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I`ve made a recursive component. One that can loop over its children ad infinitum

On the top of this component is this line, this is the first element in the vue component:

```
<component class="relative " :is="type || 'div'" v-html="computed_content" :class="computed_classes">
```

I want to show v-html if the component has no children.
I want v-html to be empty, or contain the children, if the component has children.

With v-html="" the children components can be rendered.
With a returned value from computed_content, this doesnt seem to work.

Simple example:

```
computed_content: function() {
  if (this.one_post.posts.length < 1) {
    return this.one_post.id + this.one_post.content
  }
  return --> what? false? null? ""?
},
```

What is the proper way to get this to work? show the child-components with v-html or make 2 components, 1 for with content, 1 for with child-components or is there a better solution?

Comment: I don't think you can call your component `component` there is such a think in vue, so I would think it would clash.
See here:
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

Comment: @Michael - So far this works without clashing, instead of using a vue instance, i use it to get to a hmtl or a vue element. See: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/vuejs/vuejs.org/tree/master/src/v2/examples/vue-20-dynamic-components

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can bind things (dynamically) to the component like so:

```
v-bind={content: computed_content}" . //on the component
...
computed_content: function() {
  if (this.one_post.posts.length < 1) {
    return this.one_post.id + this.one_post.content
  }
  return --> what? false? null? ""?
}
```

Comment: With v-bind, you show the content as text, i want to show the content as html. so I would like to use v-html. But when using v-html, with a variable i cant switch between an empty element or an element with content.

Comment: no, with v-bind you are merely passing the content as a prop you can then insert that into v-html if you want.

Comment: Aah, to determine at the parent component, I`ll give that a try.